# Thailand transit visa for 5 days on Pakistani passport

Tags: visas, transit, thailand, pakistani-citizens

I would like to know if one can apply or get on 
arrival a Thailand 5 days transit visa?
My husband is coming back to Australia from Pakistan and he wants to stay in Thailand for 5 days. Does he need to show some funds as well?

Comment: I don't think they'll see 5 days as transit. That's a tourist visit, even if it's happening to make use of a stopover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to know if one can apply or get on arrival a Thailand 5 days transit visa?

No to 'on arrival'. For Pakistani citizens I'm afraid that is not possible.

> Does he need to show some funds as well?

Yes. See *bank statement* below and ***contribution from @Ali Awan***.

.

The documentary requirements for a Transit visa as provided by the [Thai Embassy in Islamabad](http://www.thaiembassy.org/islamabad/contents/files/services-20160324-002613-249078.pdf):

•   Personal covering letter, mentioning: name, passport number, purpose of visit, date of travel, and other important information.

•   Letter from the organization own by/employing the applicant, mentioning; the relation of the applicant to the organization, no objection for the applicant’s travel, date of leave that the applicant took, and other important information.

•   *(Excluding governmental or international organization)* The organization’s registration paper.

•   **Two copies** of applicant’s CNIC card.

•   **Two copies** of applicant’s passport, only for the page with information of passport holder.

•   Copy of applicant’s passport, for the page with visa.

•   Copy of a visa that is the destination country.

•   Confirmed and non-refundable air ticket showing all destinations.

•   *(If staying in Thailand)* Documents relating to accommodation.

•   Applicant’s original bank statement covering at least 1 year, and a certified covering letter from the bank.

•   Documents showing the trust worthy of the applicant.

•   Other relevant supporting documents.

---

***contribution from @Ali Awan*** who visited Thailand two months ago and has a letter from their Embassy:

1)  Travellers have to have US$700 in cash. Only rarely do Thai Immigration ask about this, but it is compulsory.

2)  Residents of Punjab and Khyber Pakhtunkhwa must apply through Islamabad, Sindh and Baluchistan must apply through Karachi.

VISA INSTRUCTIONS

> The applicant has to apply along with the documents mentioned below:
>
> Two visa application forms duly filled in “Capital Letters” by the applicant to be submitted together with the following documents: 2.1 Passport must be valid for minimum six months and must be valid for Thailand. 2.2 Reference letter from your present employer bearing your job position, duration of service and salary / income. In case of business owner, please attach the requested letter on your company letterhead, your latest Certificate of Membership of Chamber of Commerce, Certificate of National Tax Number (NTN) and proof of company’s financial transactions over the past 6 months. 2.3 A photocopy of national ID card. 2.4 Two photocopies of passport (first four pages). 2.5 Two fresh passport-sized coloured photographs (3.5 x 4.5 cm). Three photographs of each child are required if accompanied. 2.6 A confirmed round trip ticket (stapled to the last page of the passport). 2.7 Your personal bank statement for the last 6 months.
>
> A foreigner, who intends to visit Thailand, must be in possession of minimum US$700 or equivalent amount in any other hard currencies at the time of entry. In case the passenger fails to prove his/her income status, he/she may be rejected and repatriated by the Thai Immigration.
>
> The applicant for Transit visa must acquire the visa of the country of destination prior to submission for visa application at the Royal Thai Embassy. In case no visa for the country of destination is required, the applicant must be supported by an air-ticket along with an invitation letter from a reliable firm or person confirming that the passage through Thailand to the country of destination has been arranged with all the documents mentioned above.
>
> FEES Transit Visa - Validity of Visa : 3 months Single Entry 3,000 Rupees Tourist Visa - Validity of Visa : 3 months Single Entry 4,000 Rupees Non-Immigrant Visa - Validity of Visa : 3 months Single Entry 8,000 Rupees Non-Immigrant Visa - Validity of Visa : One Year Multiple Entries 20,000 Rupees Note: Once submitted, the fee will not be returned to the applicant in any case.
>
> The permission to enter and the duration of stay in Thailand will be accorded and determined by the Thai Immigration only.
>
> VISA HOURS Mondays – Fridays 09.00 – 11.00 hrs except official holidays.
>
> A minimum of 4 working days (not including the date of submission) will be required for consideration and granting of visa. The applicant is advised to apply for appropriate visa in person or through the authorized Visa Drop Box Facility Agents appointed by the Embassy well in advance of the date of his/her departure to Thailand in order to prevent last minute rush.
>
> The Royal Thai Embassy reserves the rights to process the application according to the Royal Thai Government’s rules and regulations, and to issue or to reject any application without giving any reason. The Royal Thai Embassy also has the right to request from the applicant additional document other than those stated above to support his/her visa application at any time.
>
> Documents once submitted shall not be returned to the applicant.
>
> Notice: The Royal Thai Embassy does not charge any other service fees other than visa processing fees mentioned in number 5 above. ROYAL THAI EMBASSY ISLAMABAD. Tel: (92-51) 843 1270 Fax: (92-51) 8431288 E-mail: royalthaiembassyislamabad@gmail.com Website: http://www.thaiembassy.org/islamabad (19 Dec 2014)

Comment: +1, also pakistani visa issued from Islamabad and Karachi have to have 700 usd cash in possession. only rarely Thai immigration ask but it is compulsory